# SystemD: Run 3 instances of MongoDB

Tags: boot, systemd, mongodb

My current setup:

mongodb

```
me@server:/lib/systemd/system$ cat mongodb.service 
[Unit]
Description=An object/document-oriented database
Documentation=man:mongod(1)

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

mongodb.homepage1

```
me@server:/lib/systemd/system$ cat mongodb.homepage1.service 
[Unit]
Description=An object/document-oriented database
Documentation=man:mongod(1)

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.homepage1.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

mongodb.homepage2

```
me@server:/lib/systemd/system$ cat mongodb.homepage2.service 
[Unit]
Description=An object/document-oriented database
Documentation=man:mongod(1)

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.homepage2.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As you can see, all three files have the same structure.

Still `mongodb` starts on boot, whereas `mongodb.homepage1` and `mongodb.homepage2` do not.

Manual start works:

```
sudo reboot

# ... server reboots ...

sudo service mongodb start # not necessary, because this one starts automatically
sudo service mongodb.homepage1 start
sudo service mongodb.homepage2 start
```

All 3 are running on different ports configured through their different configuration files.

**Why don't they start on boot?**

Comment: You should consider writing a `mongodb@.service` template service unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled your 2 custom services. To view a list of enabled and disabled services, you use this command:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service
```

If they are disabled or not in the list, enable them:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb.homepage1
sudo systemctl enable mongodb.homepage2
```